# How do I send CSRFToken in my axios requests using Nuxt and Django on the backend?

Tags: django-rest-framework, nuxt.js, django-csrf, csrf-token

I'm using Django Rest as a backend api, and each API call requires a CSRF Token in the headers. In my "Applications" tab in Developer Tools, I clearly have a "csrftoken" value and I somehow need to extract that with each subsequent `POST` request that my Nuxt application does (using Nuxt/Axios)

My `settings.py` looks like this:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
)

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
]
CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS = ['Content-Type', 'X-CSRFToken']
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = "Lax"
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = "Lax"
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
```

I have tried using `js-cookies` with `Cookies.get("csrftoken") which just returns undefined. Is the cookie not accessible because it's set to` HTTPONLY`?

What is the recommended step here? Should I create a view in my django backend to generate a CSRF Token, and then before making each request on the frontend, I call this view in my Django app to fetch the token?

E.g

```
def get_csrf(request):
    response = JsonResponse({"detail": "CSRF cookie set"})
    response["X-CSRFToken"] = get_token(request)
    return response
```

Not sure how to proceed..

My Nuxt/Axios requests looks something like this:

```
const response = 
    await this.$axios.$post("/api/portfolios/", stockData, 
      { headers: { "X-CSRFToken": /* Need some value here.  */ } 
    });
```

I can however get the cookie using `nuxtServerInit` in my Nuxt Store:

```
            async nuxtServerInit({commit}) {
                console.log(this.$cookies.get("csrftoken")) // this works, can store it in some state
            },
```

I can store the value from `nuxtServerInit` in a Nuxt store. However, whenever I logout, how do I make sure to extract the new csrftoken from the browser? The `nuxtServerInit` part above only works if I do a page reload, which isn't ideal.

Appreciate any guidance I can get.

Answer (score 0):

Setup axios with default xsrfHeaderName and  xsrfCookieName values via nuxt plugin.
When configured, axios will include in request your csrf header with cookie value if it's present in cookies.

1. in nuxt.config.js include your new plugin

```js
// Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
plugins: [
  '~/plugins/axios',
]
```

2. create plugins/axios.js

There is the option to declare as global default config, or for a nuxt instance.

```js
// content of plugins/axios.js
/* 
// This is a global config declaration that works on any axios instance,
// meaning that if you just import axios from 'axios' in any place, you will get those.
// This will also work on the axios instance that nuxt creates and injects.

import axios from 'axios'

axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'x-csrftoken'
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'
*/
export default function ({ $axios }) {
  // This is a nuxt specific instance config, this will work in
  // everyplace where nuxt inject axios, like Vue components, and store
  $axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'x-csrftoken'
  $axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'
}
```